# What's an example of a commutative algebra over $\mathbb Q$ that fails to satisfy this version of the "PBW theorem"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lie-algebroids, pbw-theorems, differential-operators

In a [recent question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81446/for-which-algebras-does-differential-operators-satisfy-a-pbw-like-theorem), I recalled the notion of *differential operator*, *polyderivation*, and *principal symbol* for a commutative algebra $A$ over some fixed commutative ring $k$.  (I will not repeat those definitions here, because you can read them there.)  In that question, I asked for sufficient conditions to assure that $A$ satisfied the following version of the "PBW theorem": whether the principal symbol map (which I called $s_n$) from ($n$th order) differential operators to ($n$th order) polyderivations is a surjection.

I thought I had an example to show that it is not always a surjection, but in the comments [Vladimir Dotsenko](https://mathoverflow.net/users/1306/vladimir-dotsenko) pointed out that I was wrong.  In fact, I have since been unable to come up with any counterexample to this "PBW theorem".

Because for some other part of my project I must restrict to the situation when $k\supseteq \mathbb Q$ (essentially because I only know how to define the commutator of polyderivations in that case), I will ask my question there:

> **Question:** What's an explicit example of a commutative algebra $A$ over a commutative ring $k\supseteq \mathbb Q$ such that there exists a polyderivation $A^{\otimes n} \to A$ which is not the principal symbol of any differential operator.

If you can show that no such algebra exists, then I will gladly accept your answer both here and as an answer to my previous question.

Comment: It seems plausible that such an example could come from a ring $A$ whose ring of differential operators is not Noetherian.

One standard such example is the coordinate ring of the cubic cone in $\mathbb{C}^3$.

You can find more details here: 

http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~bernstei/Publication_list/publication_texts/BGG-Op-Cubic-cone-Usp.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me try to give a naive answer. Consider the following symmetric triderivation on $A=k[x]/x^2$: 
$$
x\partial_x\otimes\partial_x\otimes\partial_x:(x,x,x)\mapsto x
$$
How could it be in the image of $s_3$, considering that any differential operator on $A$ is of order $\leq 2$?

Comment: Yes, of course, I was being blind.