# An alternative representation of the principal symbol of the Laplace operator

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, differential-operators, laplacian

Assume that $(M,g)$ is a $n$ dimensional Riemannian manifold. We denote by $\Delta$, the Laplacian associated to this Riemannian structure.
Are the following two conditions equivalent?

**First condition 1)** [There exist globally defined vector fields $X_i's,\quad i=1,2,\ldots,n$ such that $$\Delta=\sum_{i=1}^n \partial^2/\partial{X_i^2}$$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/213072/can-the-laplace-operator-on-n-manifolds-be-represented-as-a-sum-of-n-second)

**Second condition 2)** There exsits a first order differential operator $D$ on $\chi^{\infty}(M)$ such that at each cotangent vector in $T^*(M)$ we have $$(*)\;\;\;{Det(P(D))}^2= {P(\Delta)}^n$$ where $"P"$ stand for the principal symbol of the corresponding operator.

> If the answer to the question is negative, what kind of obstructions would appear to have the "Second condition 2"? Does every Riemannian manifold   admit such a differential operator $D$ on $\chi^{\infty}(M)$? Apart from obvious examples in dimension $1,2,4,8$, are there some other examples(in other dimension)?
>
> What about if we replace $(*)$ with $$trace (P(D)P(D)^{tr})=nP(\Delta)$$
> Note that $P(D)^{tr}$, the transpos of $P(D)$, is uniquely well defined since each fiber of the bundle $q^*(TM)$, the pull back of $TM$ over $M$ under the natural projection $q:T^*M \to M$ is equiped with an inner product via vector bundle pull back of the metric of fibers of $TM$.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but your condition (1) is equivalent to having n globally defined divergence-free orthonormal vector fields.

Comment: @Raziel  Thank you. Let me to think about this equivalenty you mentioned.

Comment: @Raziel If I am not mistaken it is also mentioed in some amswer to the linked question, yes?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the first question is negative on the Euclidean sphere $\mathbb S^2$. It is possible to prove that the Laplace operator on the sphere $\mathbb S^2$ is NOT the sum of two squares of smooth vector fields.

However, you can always consider on the sphere $\mathbb S^d$ the $d(d-1)/2$ vector fields
$$
\Omega_{jk}=x_j\partial_{x_k}-x_k\partial_{x_j}, \quad 1\le j<k\le d,
$$ 
and you have indeed
$
∆_{\mathbb S^{d-1}}=\sum_{1\le j<k\le d} \Omega_{jk}^2.
$

For your second question, assuming say that your manifold $(\mathcal M, g)$
is compact, the positive Laplace operator $A$ is a self-adjoint operator and by the functional calculus, you can define $B=A^{1/2}$ which is in fact a pseudo-differential operator of order 1, whose principal symbol is $b$ and such that $b^2=a$, where $a$ is the principal symbol of $A$. The downside of that approach is that the operator $A^{1/2}$ is never a differential operator.

Comment: Yes But in dimension 1,2,4,8 there are already example od differential operators which represent  the symbol of Laplacian.